# Can anyone please explain the working of the below line?

Tags: python-3.x

```
"\n".join([string[i:i+max_width] for i in range(0, len(string), max_width)])
```

here,
String - Input String
max_width = a integer value

Ex - input- `abcdefghij`
to
output -

```
ab
cd
ef
gh
ij
```

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so:

```
range(0, len(string), max_width)
```

this returns an iterable of integers starting from 0, ending at len(string) - 1, with a stride of max_width, so for max_width = 3, it would give us 0, 3, 6, 9, ...

```
string[a:b]
```

is a slicing syntax, so

```
'abcdefgh'[2:5] = 'cde'
```

Finally, the join function inserts a newline character between all of those arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Given a String this Code consists of different parts:

`string[i:i+max_width]` accesses several characters within the string (depending on max_width) and returns them. Join joins these returns together with a newline inbetween. This happens for `range(0, len(string), max_width)` meaning, that we range from `0` to `len(string)-1` with steps of size `max_width`, which is `2` in this example. This means for your input we take every two chars of the string and seperate them by newline.

Comment: Got it, Thank you

Comment: Feel free to mark my or the other question as an answer if that was what you are looking for, so the question is "closed".